# Repeated error about transparency on icon in expo build despite no transparency

Tags: ios, expo, app-store

There is another question with a similar title but the answers there aren't helping

As the title explains I keep getting an error when submitting my app to the IOS platform `eas submit -p ios --latest`

```
Your iOS app icon is missing or is an invalid format. The icon must be a 1024x1024 PNG image with no transparency.
Check your icon image and icon configuration in app.json.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/app-icons/
```

I made sure that the icon is the correct size 1024*1024 and that the transparency is removed.
I also tripled checked that the path to the icon is correct, any other ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Below is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my app",
    "scheme": "com.maypp.app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",

    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "expo-apple-authentication"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "myapp.ai.app",
      "buildNumber": "1"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.maypp.app",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/icons/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "592042c4-13cc-49ab-8654-13a6702c9c8c"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After adding the icon to the same folder as the app.json it worked, I hope this helps someone in the future